# How to build asynchronous app in python?

Tags: python, websocket, rabbitmq, celery

I want to build Python app for asynchronic data downloading, processing and sending to client. I don't know if I projected it correctly.

1. Requests from desktop client.
2. Messages to workers.
3. Downloading API data.
4. Sending processed data to client, every 10 seconds.

What Python library should I use for server-client data sending?
I'm going to use Websockets, but I don't know if it's the best idea.

Will http be good way to send requests to server (1)?

Do I need additional server between Client and message broker ? If yes, what framework will be the best for it?

[image]

Comment: Please read this example https://github.com/Gsantomaggio/rabbitmqexample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/). You will need a server to manage websockets connections. The flow is:

1. Open a websockets connection to the server
2. Send request to the server to download a resource from API Provider
3. Delegate download task to celery worker
4. Once the data is ready (downloaded and processed) push it back to client.

Comment: Why should I use Tornado instead of Twisted in my project?

Comment: Tornado is a web framework with all the benefits that come with it (one of the is celery integration), Twisted is more of a library (or as they description says - engine) which can implement web-server.
You can use Twisted for your project, but it would make celery integration a bit more difficult and other web-framework features non-existent.